# Is there any way to profile the performance of views in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-mvc-2, profiling, view

I am profiling my MVC app and the speed from the Performance Explorer is around 500 ms (50 ms code, 450ms SQL roundtrips that won't exist in deployment).

However, the time taken waiting on a response to a GET request is around 1200ms.

I've managed to discover through trial and error that this is due to a particularly slow partial view.

However, is there any way for me to discover this through profiling in the future?

If it helps I am using precompiled Spark views but a solution that works for this or the default view engine would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a profiler. What stops you from just attaching a profiler for ASP.NET and look where the time is spent?

Comment: Any examples of a profiler to use? The point I was making was that I do have the Visual Studio profiler attached to the ASP.NET code and it ignores view execution time.

Comment: Well, I use the Visual Studio Team System 2010 profiler ;) I can attach it to code (running in debug mode preferably) and / or just start a profiling run directly from the IDE.

Comment: It must be because my views are precompiled. I can't get it to attach to view rendering, only controller execution. Thanks though.